# browser storage using javascript pt.2

Tags: javascript, html, css

in this program I'm trying to create a from for people to fill out. However, everything is supposed to be stored into the browser storage.

The problem I keep running into is the arrival date keeps printing out "undefined" and the if "smoking" out keeps printing yes.. even if you dont check the box.

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var saveReservation = function() {
    
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("name", name);
    
 var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("phone", phone);
    
 var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("email", email);
    
 var arrival_date = document.getElementById("arrival_date").value;
    sessionStorage.setItem("arrival_date", arrival_date);
    
 var nights = document.getElementById("nights").value;
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("nights", nights);
 var adults = document.getElementById("adults").value;
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("adults", adults);
 var children = document.getElementById("children").value;
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("children", children);
 var standard = document.getElementById("standard").value;
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("roomType", standard);
 var king = document.getElementById("king").value;
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("bedType", king);
 var smoking = document.getElementById("smoking").value;
    
    sessionStorage.setItem("smoking", smoking);
 
 
    // submit form
    $("reservation_form").submit();
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("submit_request").onclick = saveReservation;
    $("arrival_date").focus();
};
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
fieldset {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: .5em;
}
legend {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 85%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
}
input, select {
    margin-left: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
input {
    width: 14em; 
}
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 1em;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reservation request</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reservation.css">
    <script src="reservation.js"></script>
</head>
 
<body>
    <main>
 <h1>Reservation Request</h1>
 <form action="response.html" method="get"
     name="reservation_form" id="reservation_form">
            <fieldset>
         <legend>General Information</legend>
         <label for="arrival_date">Arrival date:</label>
         <input type="text" name="arrival_date" id="arrival_date"><br>
         <label for="nights">Nights:</label>
         <input type="text" name="nights" id="nights"><br>
         <label>Adults:</label>
         <select name="adults" id="adults">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                              
         </select><br>
         <label>Children:</label>
         <select name="children" id="children">
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>                              
         </select><br>         
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
         <legend>Preferences</legend>
         <label>Room type:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="room" id="standard" value="standard" checked>Standard          
  <input type="radio" name="room" id="business" value="business">Business
  <input type="radio" name="room" id="suite" value="suite">Suite<br>
                
         <label>Bed type:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="bed" id="king" value="king" checked>King
  <input type="radio" name="bed" id="double" value="double">Double Double<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="smoking" id="smoking" value="smoking">Smoking<br>
            </fieldset>  
            <fieldset>
      <legend>Contact Information</legend>
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
         <label for="email">Email:</label>
         <input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br>
  <label for="phone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="button" id="submit_request" value="Submit Reservation"><br>
 </form>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- response -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reservation Request</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reservation.css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <script> 
            document.write("<h3>The following reservation has been submitted</h3>");
            document.write("Name: ", sessionStorage.name, "<br>");
            document.write("Phone: ", sessionStorage.phone, "<br>");
            document.write("Email: ", sessionStorage.email, "<br>");
            document.write("Arrival Date: ", sessionStorage.arrivalDate, "<br>");
            document.write("Nights: ", sessionStorage.nights, "<br>");
            document.write("Adults: ", sessionStorage.adults, "<br>");
            document.write("Children: ", sessionStorage.children, "<br>");
            document.write("Room Type: ", sessionStorage.roomType, "<br>");
            document.write("Bed Type: ", sessionStorage.bedType, "<br>");
            document.write("Smoking: ", sessionStorage.smoking, "<br><br>");
        </script>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems to be working fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZYpmg as long as cookies are not deleted. Since HTML5 you also have localstorage ...

Comment: @GCyrillus  i know it works fine, though the two parts are unresponsive when ran: smoking and arrive date

Comment: You have mistaken the `var` names for `arrivalDate`, wich should be `arrival_date` . For the smoking, you need to check if the input is checked or note to reset its value to yes or no (here it will always be smoking) or use a select/option list.http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zZYpmg?editors=1010